# Making a basic Javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, html

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EptAN/1/)

Bear with me, total newb here.

I'm trying to make a simple multiplication calculator, as a experimentation with Javascript.

The catch is that -

1. No libraries, just pure javascript.
2. Javascript must be unobtrusive.

Now, the problem arises, that it doesn't give the value out.

When I do this locally, `answer` has a value of `NaN`, and if you hit `Submit` it stays that way, BUT, if you press the back button, you see the actual result.

In the JSFiddle, much is not shown, except for the fact that it simply doesn't work.

Please tell me, is it even possible to make an unobtrusive calculator? How?

(PS. I was taking a bit of help from [sciencebuddies](http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/CompSci_p001.shtml), just to see basic syntax and stuff, but I found it can't be done without code being obtrusive)

Comment: The `xintox.js` file is not included; also, all you need in the `html` frame is what's *in* the `body` (not the `body` element itself); you can add resources through the Resources menu on the left.

Comment: Also, you can't just say `Xintox.blahblahblah`. You need to use a method like `document.getElementByName`.

Comment: I must have forgot to remove the script code, the xintox.js is the JS provided in the fiddle itself. There is no more code, except in the fiddle.

Comment: Edited but you need to add the Xintox and CSS resources: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EptAN/2/ @Linuxios - That may be true, but see the `getE()` function in my edited fiddle.

Comment: @Linuxios, I have added the getE in my own, original fiddle. Also, I saw the formname.formelementname method [http://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project_ideas/CompSci_p001.shtml](here), is it deprecated or something?

Comment: @Namanyayg: Probably, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Namanyayg jsfiddle provides the `<head>` and `<body>` wrapper - the HTML you provide should assume it's inside the `<body>`

Comment: On a related note: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/R3Gmg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize you're probably just getting started and don't know what to include, remove, and whatnot. But, good advice here, clearly label your elements so you can understand them, and pare it down to the smallest possible code you need for it to work (even less, so you can build it up).

Here is your code reworked:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="multiplicand" value="4">
    <input type="text" id="multiplier" value="10">
    <button type="button" id="multiply">Multiply</button>
</div>
<p id="result">
    The product is: <span id="product">&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var button = el('multiply'),
        multiplicand = el('multiplicand'),
        multiplier = el('multiplier'),
        product = el('product');

    function el(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    };

    function multiply() {
        var x = parseFloat(multiplicand.value) || 0,
            y = parseFloat(multiplier.value) || 0;

        product.innerHTML = x * y;
    }

    button.onclick = multiply;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EptAN/6/

A slightly more sophisticated approach, with add/subtract/multiply/divide:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EptAN/9/

Comment: Might want to add `type=button` to the `<button>` tag because in some browsers the type defaults to "submit".

Comment: Thanks a lot! :D

EDIT:

Could you explain where did I go wrong?

Comment: Just in case someone wonders, the `... || 0` part means if `...` was `NaN or 0`, use the value `0`

Comment: @ajax333221 , how is it decided whether parseFloat is to be chosen, or 0? Does parseFloat give a value of False or something, in case NaN is found? AFAIK, || = or, right?

Comment: @Namanyayg - See this fiddle for a way to see if you're multiplying by `0` (which I evaluate `NaN` to with the `|| 0`, as ajax333221 notes).

Comment: @Namanyayg - There was actually a lot of mess in what you had, so it's difficult to say specifically, other than it was a mess (which is a problem when you're writing code). Note the organization in the code above; that's on purpose. Also note, yes, if you say `var a = b || c`, if `b` evaluates to `false`, it will use `c` instead. It's a cheaper way of writing a simple `if` statement.

Comment: @Namanyayg - And... You can see I have `,` at the end of the `var`s, which allows me to declare each with one `var` statement. I prefer it, more or less, than `var a...; var b...;`, but you do have to be careful with the `,` is put at the end of each non-terminating line.

Comment: Thankyou Jared. 

I'll firstly try substituting submit for button, and removing the form tag, and using GetDocumentById, then I hope to learn where I went wrong.

Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Namanyayg - Alright, may this would help if you can see how you could develop it into a more "sophisticated" script. Try adding (to what I've got in my fiddle above) the means to select add, substract, multiply, and divide. If you hit a road block or just can't get it to work, try: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EptAN/9/ Try not to look, though, unless you have to or you get it to work.

Comment: One more thing - Why is the code 'inverted'? ie, First you use el, then define it?

Comment: Thanks for this task! I'll surely attempt it, hopefully, I'll solve it myself.

Could you tell me a place where I can look about the syntax? I honestly don't know what changes if a option button is clicked.

Comment: @Namanyayg - That's called ["hoisting"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting); I considered explaining that, but it's potentially confusing. Good catch. Basically, if you declare a `var` or `function`, it is "hoisted" to the top of the scope as if it were declared before everything else. Note, `functionExpression`s don't have this effect per se (you'll have the variable, but not the function to call), so `var func = function(){...};` don't have this behavior; you can't call it seemingly before it's "declared".

Comment: @Namanyayg - Personally, I would suggest [MDN's Javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript), which includes tutorials.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really didn't understand hoisting fully, in time. Also, thanks for the MDN documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the submit button so that it doesn't submit the form.  Right now clicking "Submit" causes the form submits to the same page which involves a page reload.

Change the `<input type="submit" id="submitt">` to `<button type=button>` and it should work.

You can probably do without the `<form>` element in the first place. That'll stop clicking enter in your text input from reloading the page.

Comment: No, it still won't work properly, but that's definitely necessary.

Comment: I thought that the form "binds" them together, and I saw the syntax formname.formelement.value, so I thought that's the way to go. Thanks for this :D

@Pointy what more is to be added?

Comment: Well Jared Famish has given a pretty thorough answer that covers things well.

Comment: @Namanyayg, the onclick handler binds them together sufficiently well without the side effect of wiping out the current page state.

Answer (score 1):

Your example has a couple of problems:

1. The form still submits.  After the JS changes the value, the submit will cause the page to reload, and that work you've done setting the answer value is wasted.
2. You're trying to do this stuff right away.  In the header, none of the body has been parsed yet (and thus, the form elements don't even exist).  You'll want to wait til the page is loaded.
3. The script hijacks `window.onload`.  If you don't have any other scripts on the page, that's fine...but the whole point of unobtrusive JS (IMO) is that nothing breaks whether the script is there or not.

Fixed, we have something kinda like:

```
// Wrap this onload in an IIFE that we pass the old onload to, so we can
// let it run too (rather than just replacing it)
(function(old_onload) {

  // attach this code to onload, so it'll run after everything exists
  window.onload = function(event) {

    // run the previous onload
    if (old_onload) old_onload.call(window, event);

    document.getElementById('Xintox').onsubmit = function() {
      var multiplier = +this.multiplier.value;
      var multiplicand = +this.multiplicand.value;
      this.answer.value = multiplier * multiplicand;
      return false;  // keep the form from submitting
    };
  };​
})(window.onload);
```

Note i'm attaching the meat code to the form, rather than the button, because hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in either of the factor boxes will trigger a submit as well.  You could still attach to the button if you wanted, and just add a submit handler that returns false.  But IMO it's better this way -- that way the form works just the same with JS as without (assuming the script on the server fills in the boxes appropriately), except it won't require a round trip to the server.

Comment: A few questions -  
What's an IIFE?  
How does using old_onload help?  
Why is there a bracket before 'function'?  
Explain the 'if' statement please? Shouldn't it have {} ?  
What does +this mean?  
What does this.answer.value give? Does 'this' here means 'Xintox' ? 
What does the (window.onload) at the end do?  

Thanks :)

Comment: An IIFE ("Immediately Invoked Function Expression") is a function that you execute right as you define it, often without even so much as giving it a name.  `(function() {})()` is an IIFE.  It's used to avoid globals, and/or to rename stuff within the function. (You'll often see it in jQuery plugins, in the form `(function($) {...})(jQuery)`, because `$` is convenient and stands out, but other scripts may have hijacked it).  You could say `var old_onload = window.onload;` and forgo the IIFE, but since it's running in the global scope, `old_onload` is global even though you use `var`.

Comment: The `if` statement calls the old onload if there was one.  We can't be sure whether it was there or not, so we can't just call it.  You don't need the `{}` because it's a single statement; you only *need* `{}` if you have more than one statement to execute.  (Some people say to use them always, but they don't really serve a purpose in this case.)

Comment: `+expression` is one of a few ways to cast `expression` to a number.  Works kinda like `parseInt`, but uses JS's type coercion rules.  See, `+` (as a unary operator) takes a number, and...well...doesn't do anything to it.  (It's there for symmetry with `-`, and is equivalent to `-(-expression)`, but without the extraneous math.)  But it only works on numbers, so JS casts `expression` to a number for you.

Comment: Since the event handler is a property of the form, and will conceptually be called somewhat like `theForm.onsubmit(event)` by the browser on submit, when it runs `this` is set to the form element.  In this case, yes, that's the form with the id of "Xintox".

Comment: And finally, `(window.onload)` at the end is the rest of the IIFE.  That's the part that actually *calls* the function, passing it the existing `window.onload` so we can piggyback it.